# How to set distance bewteen text and footnote in minipage?

Tags: tables, footnotes, minipage

I have something like this:

```
\begin{table}
   \centering
   \let\footnoterule\empty
   \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
   \begin{minipage}[c]{\textwidth}
      \centering
      \begin{tabular}{cc}
         \hline
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. & Mauris ut leo\footnote{This is a footnote.} \\
          Curabitur auctor semper nulla.                            & Cras viverra metus\footnote{Another footnote.} \\
          \hline
       \end{tabular}
   \end{minipage}
   \caption{This is a caption.\label{fig}}
 \end{table}
```

I would like to know how to set the distance between the end of the tabular and the footnote 'a'. I have read `source2e.pdf`, 60.2, but I'm not able to understand which macro produces this vertical space.

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.\footnote{\lipsum[2]}


\begin{table}
\centering
\let\footnoterule\empty
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\begin{minipage}[c]{\textwidth}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{cc}
\hline
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. & Mauris ut leo\footnote{This is a footnote.} \\
Curabitur auctor semper nulla.                            & Cras viverra metus\footnote{Another footnote.} \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}
\caption{This is a caption.\label{fig}}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you want them placed in the table or at the page bottom?

Comment: @Bobyandbob I would like these footnotes appear immediately under table with vertical distance equal to `\medskipamount`.

Answer (score 1):

LaTeX source has the following lines

```
\def\endminipage{%
    \par
    \unskip
    \ifvoid\@mpfootins\else
      \vskip\skip\@mpfootins
      \normalcolor
      \footnoterule
      \unvbox\@mpfootins
    \fi
    \@minipagefalse   %% added 24 May 89
  \color@endgroup
  \egroup
  \expandafter\@iiiparbox\@mpargs{\unvbox\@tempboxa}}
```

So let us locally add 1in before footnotes:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.\footnote{\lipsum[2]}


\begin{table}
\centering
\let\footnoterule\empty
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\makeatletter
\skip\@mpfootins=1in
\makeatother
\begin{minipage}[c]{\textwidth}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{cc}
\hline
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. & Mauris ut leo\footnote{This is a footnote.} \\
Curabitur auctor semper nulla.                            & Cras viverra metus\footnote{Another footnote.} \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}
\caption{This is a caption.\label{fig}}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]